# Generate unique div id in php to assign javascript to it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I generate the following pieces of code via php (unknown number in advance) and they are all wrapper in my 'item-container' div:

```
<div id="item-size" class="item-size">
    <div class="view pic-transition"> 
        <figure id="ribbonnew" class="ribbonnew">
            <img class="ribbonnewimg" alt="" src="../images/endingsoonribbon.png">
        </figure>
            <img src="../images/woman.jpg" /> 
            <div class="mask"> 
                <h2>Title</h2> 
                <p>This is a test of a description for an item.</p> 
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a> 
            </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I generate a ribbon on **SOME** of these 'item-size' div's and via javascript i want the ribbon to be hidden when the mouse is hovered over and back to normal when mouse out. 
My javascript code is:

```
$("#item-size").hover(function(){
       $('#ribbonnew').hide();
   },function(){
       $('#ribbonnew').show();
});
```

This of course only works for the first element, so I guess I need to assign ID's to the 'item-size' div's ? How do I do this AND create the javascript which binds the mouse hover to every of these divs (how to pass the size of how many I created, so I could add ID's from 0 to size)?

*As an extra question, is there also a way to make the ribbon fade in and fade out slowly? .fadeOut(1000); is not delivering the expected result*

Comment: Why can't you use classes? What does `fadeOut` do that you don't want?

Comment: fadeOut makes it dissapear immediately instead of fading away, .fadeOut(1000) just instantly pops it off the screen. same goes for .hide("slow")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all ids :

```
<div class="item-size">
    <div class="view pic-transition"> 
        <figure class="ribbonnew">
            <img class="ribbonnewimg" alt="" src="../images/endingsoonribbon.png">
        </figure>
        <img src="../images/woman.jpg" /> 
        <div class="mask"> 
            <h2>Title</h2> 
            <p>This is a test of a description for an item.</p> 
            <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And use a dot `.` in your selectors to match elements by classes :

```
$(".item-size").hover(function(){
       $(this).find('.ribbonnew').hide();
   },function(){
       $(this).find('.ribbonnew').show();
});
```

For your extra question, you can use a parameter in the [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) jquery methods for animation :

```
$(this).find('.ribbonnew').hide(400);
```

Edit : if the html is inserted dynamically, try event delagation instead :

```
$('#item-container').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.item-size', function(){
    $(this).find('.ribbonnew').toggle(400);
});
```

Comment: was in de middle of typing exactly this when you posted ;)

Comment: It does work perfect if I copy the HTML directly in the php file, but if I generate this from another PHP file and output it via AJAX this does not work anymore! And the animation is not really working as intended. fadeOut makes it dissapear immediately instead of fading away, .fadeOut(1000) just instantly pops it off the screen. same goes for .hide("slow")

Comment: See my edit. The animation should work BTW. What version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed working for the generated code! I am using jQuery 1.11.1 I think I understood the jQuery animation wrong, I was hoping it would be a slow fading animation going from invisible-->barely visible-->visible, but right now it just pops from visible to invisible immediately and on mouseout it immediately pops back up after the inserted delay (in parameter).

Comment: You can use `fadeToggle()` for this : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/jLett4p1/) or the [oposite](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/jLett4p1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

(if you really want to use ids)

Generate a unique id using the `uniqid()` function, and name all your `item-size` elements.

```
<?php
    $unique_id = uniqid();
?>
<div id="<?=$unique_id?>item-size" class="item-size">
    <div class="view pic-transition"> 
        <figure class="ribbonnew">
            <img class="ribbonnewimg" alt="" src="../images/endingsoonribbon.png">
        </figure>
            <img src="../images/woman.jpg" /> 
            <div class="mask"> 
                <h2>Title</h2> 
                <p>This is a test of a description for an item.</p> 
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a> 
            </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, match all elements with that unique id as part of their ids.

```
$("*[id^='<?=$unique_id?>']").hover(function(){
   $(this).find('figure.ribbonnew').hide();
},function(){
   $(this).find('figure.ribbonnew').show();
});
```